# Google Map draw Polyline following device direction in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, cllocationmanager, google-polyline

I'am doing a navigation App, that uses Google map direction API, i ask Google Api to draw path between two coordinates with "driving mode", and i draw it on map. I have an issue when i'm driving, i recalculate path from my current location to some destination location, but the path i get is not following up my device direction,it runs in the opposite direction when i'am driving in a double direction road.

I didn't find any solution to do that. (you can see the screen shots i did with my iphone at this link : https://imageshack.com/my/images)

Thanks for help.

Comment: user bearing to correct this by using CLLocationDirection

Comment: thanks for you response, i posted my code if you want to check it,in that way, the Polyline path will follow my location direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for your reply, i did this: 
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{

    if (newHeading.headingAccuracy < 0)
        return;

    // Use the true heading if it is valid.
    CLLocationDirection  theHeading = ((newHeading.trueHeading > 0) ?
                                       newHeading.trueHeading : newHeading.magneticHeading);

    [map.mapView animateToBearing:currenHeading];
    userLocation = manager.location;
    markerUserLocation.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude,userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    markerUserLocation.map=map.mapView;
    [map.mapView animateToViewingAngle:50];
    [map.mapView animateToZoom:19];

    currenHeading = theHeading;
    if(etapes.count > 0)
    {
    //Here i start navigation        
     [self NavigateToLeg:etapes];

    }

}

and the function NavigatToLeg: 

 -(void)NavigateToLeg:(NSMutableArray *)Steps {
polyline.map = nil;
        polyline = nil;

        NSDictionary *routes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"][0];
        NSDictionary *route = [routes objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
        NSString *overview_route = [route objectForKey:@"points"];

        /******************************** ON TRACE LE CHEMIN ************************************/
        GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:overview_route];
        polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
        polyline.strokeWidth = 10.f;
        polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        polyline.map = map.mapView;
        /******************************** FIN ************************************/

        /******************************** ON RECUPERE LES ETAPES ET ON LANCE LA NAVIGATION ************************************/

        // on récupère les indications avec leurs coordonnées :
        NSArray * legs = [routes objectForKey:@"legs"];
        etapes = [[legs objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"steps"];
 NSLog(@"ETAPES COUNT = %d",etapes.count);
    NSLog(@"ETAPES NUMERO = %d",etapeCount);


    if(etapeCount < etapes.count){
    leg = [self getLegFromSteps:Steps forIndex:etapeCount];
    distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d m",[self roundUpDistance:(int)[userLocation distanceFromLocation:leg.endLoc]]];
    //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d m",[self roundUpDistance:leg.distance]];


    NSLog(@"Polyline Points: %@",leg.polyline.path);

    leg.polyline.strokeWidth = 10.f;
    leg.polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    leg.polyline.map = map.mapView;
    //[map.mapView animateToLocation:userLocation.coordinate];
    [map.mapView animateToViewingAngle:50];
    [map.mapView animateToZoom:19];

}
```

In doing this, the Path will follow my direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you are using google api to draw routes?
You can also draw routes using GPS points that you get in location manager.

Comment: The issue is that your mobile GPS point is not exactly similar as Google API respond. So its better to render path use you Device GPS Points that yu received from Location manager update.

Comment: How i'm going to render path without Google Api and how can i get roads?

Comment: But Google Map works with Google Api and it never show the opposite direction of my road.